# Can I use only hiragana when writing words/sentences?

Tags: learning, hiragana

This might seem like a dumb repeated question but I need to confirm 100% so bear with me please.

I started learning Hiragana and I can now write the vowels + the K things. I'm really good at memorizing words and pronouncing and I know lots of Japanese words. I'm saying now, is it advised to try writing the words I already know only with hiragana? For example kako (past) koko (here) etc.. Is that a good idea? Or is it even ok to do at all? And is it correct to write a whole sentence with hiragana?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29466/5010 And ここ is usually written in hiragana and 過去【かこ】 is usually written in kanji (see [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3733/5010)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'd get a handle on learning the two sets of kana before even starting with kanji.

Now for your actual question: Yes, it is 100% okay to write something entirely in hiragana. The use of kanji vs. kana is entirely up to the writer, and there is no right or wrong when it comes to that. The reasons you will see things written in kanji more frequently are:

1. Less total symbols (if you write everything in kana, it will look a bit messy/cluttered)
2. Stylistic choice
3. Identifying meaning in the case of homophones

And probably some others. But you absolutely can write in 100% hiragana if you wish. Hell, I've seen entire games written in kana.

Comment: [On very rare occasions we do this intentionally](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15108/5010), but calling it stylistic choice is too much for a beginner. We learn kanji from grade one. Without knowing kanji, you can understand nothing but a picture book for small kids. An all-kana game is probably either a game for kindergartners or a game on NES/Game Boy in the 1980's (kanji was not available then).

Comment: @naruto I was actually referring to Earthbound (Mother 2) and Mother 3, which Shigesato Itoi chose to write entirely in kana (since people don't "speak" in kanji). Pokemon games are also typically written in kana, but that's probably because very young children also play them. Either way, the point I was trying to make is that it isn't "wrong" to write entirely in kana.

Comment: OK, I can't agree it's "100% okay," but I can agree that it's not "wrong".

Comment: I played one pokemon game all in kana, and it was a nightmare. Kanji really aids reading speed and comprehension.

Comment: Well, seems like I'm going to be a child for now. Thanks for your answer, I'll make sure to finish the kana before looking at kanji.
Thing is.. my handwriting, I suck at that thing even in my first language.