# Is おんえがいします different than お願いします?

Tags: words, kanji, hiragana

I'm fairly new to the language so please bear with my stupidity regarding these type of questions.

Okay so why is
お願いします (onegaishimasu in Hiragana and 願 from i don't know) = "Please"
but
<strike>おんえおねがいします (same but all in Hiragana) = "I'm planning to do my best?"
(google translated, I don't know the accuracy)</strike>  Yep I'm stupid.

Same to 神様 (Kanji, I guess?) and カミサマ (Hiragana) which both means god.

are these what they call Kanji? When should it be used?

Comment: Okay I get it now. Should've searched before posting. Waiting for the delete button or someone from the dev to delete this.

Comment: Are they what you need? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1930/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29466/7810

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Are you asking if お**んえ**がいします is the same as お**ね**がいします, or if the all-kana word means the same thing when written in kanji?

Answer (score 2):

おんえがいします is wrong, it does not exist.

Remember that when you are learning japanese the first thing you have to learn correctly is Hiragana and then Katakana so you won't make mistakes like this one.

In romaji is onegaishimasu but the problem with romaji is that you don't know exactly where to split the syllables.
The word is written correctly like this:

> おねがいします: O - NE - GA - I - SHI - MA - SU

The wrong one that you have is written like this:

> おんえがいします: O - N - E - GA - I - SHI - MA - SU

The las one:

> お願いします

Is written in a different writing system called kanji. You should google the 4 japanese writing systems: Hiragana, Katakana, Kanji and Romaji

Finally 神様 in hiragana is written like this way かみさま, the one that you mentioned (カミサマ) is katakana.

In a nutshell, yeah you can write Kanji with hiragana for example 勉強 (Kanji) - べんきょう(Hiragana) - BE-N-KYO-U. Why is this posible? because Kanji is a pictografic writing system this means that any character represent an idea and not a sound (like ancient hieroglyphics) and Hiragana and Katakana are syllables writing systems so you can represent how a kanji is pronounced or written by syllables.

Answer (score 0):

To have a better undestanding on how to write, try to think in this way:
the syllables (vowels) in Japanese are "a i u e o", so with the letter n it would be "na ni nu ne no" (Care, it's not always like this, as with the letter t it's "ta chi tsu te to".

If the word you want to say is a consontant followed by a vowel, then DO NOT separate like you did.

If on the other side you want to extend a sound, for example, 女{おんな} it's not pronounced like "ONA", but with an extension in the N. Something like "onnnna".

Keep that in mind!

Answer (score -2):

They are basically the same, but instead of おんえがいします you should write おねがいします